# Consulta EF6 con Filtros Optimizada

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

estoy trabajando en un Backoffice.

***Mi Problema***

"Las consultas con filtros demoran entre 40 y 60 segundos o más, quisiera saber si es problema de Performance pertenece a mi Consulta, o si la base de datos que es vieja, escasa de Índices. Localmente funcionaba perfecto."

**Panorama Actual**

Actualmente acabo de hacer un Deploy sobre PreProd.

Tablas de Base de Datos testeando:

```
  Logs <== Transactions ==> TransactionType
```

Por ende Entity en la consulta Trae todo los Logs de cada Transacción y el tipo de transacción. Por cada Transacción se generan 4-5 Logs.
La base de Datos tiene 3 millones de Transacciones y unos 19 millones de logs.

Al momento de hacer un `db.Transactions.Take(100)` lo hace rápido.

Pero al momento de utilizar un filtro para una consulta mucho más personalizada demora entre 40 y 50 segundos, o más y ésto a veces me genera **TimeOut**.

Este es un ejemplo de la consulta con **Filtro**

La Consulta la mejoré con la generación de un Query Dinamico pero sigue igual

**Revivo el Tema porque me interesa**

1- Clase a Obtener desde Base de Datos:

```
public partial class Transaction
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Transaction()
    {
        Logs = new HashSet<Log>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int Status_Id { get; set; }

    public int TransactionNumber { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Client { get; set; }

    public decimal Amount { get; set; }

    public int Currency { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string BankCode { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string BankAccount { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string BankAccountType { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string ServiceCode { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(1000)]
    public string Request { get; set; }

    public int? TransactionType_Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime? LastModificationDate { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string AuditNumber { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string AppId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string EntityCode { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string BillingNumber { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Log> Logs { get; set; }

    public virtual Status Status { get; set; }

    public virtual TransactionType TransactionType { get; set; }
}
```

2- Clases Pertenecen a Transaction

```
public partial class Log
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int Operation_Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Information { get; set; }

    public int Transaction_Id { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual Transaction Transaction { get; set; }
}

public partial class Status
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Status()
    {
        Transfers = new HashSet<Transfer>();
        Transactions = new HashSet<Transaction>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(45)]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Transfer> Transfers { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }
}

[Table("TransactionType")]
public partial class TransactionType
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public TransactionType()
    {
        Transactions = new HashSet<Transaction>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }
}
```

3- Generación del Query para el Where con Filtros

```
public IQueryable<Crosslayer.Transaction> GetQuery(Crosslayer.Filters.TransactionModel filter)
    {
        IQueryable<Crosslayer.Transaction> query = db.Set<Crosslayer.Transaction>();
        string[] AppType = FormatIntToArrayString(filter.AppTypeArray, 2);
        string[] bankAccountArr = FormatIntToArrayString(filter.BankAccountTypeArray, 2);
        // assuming that you return all records when nothing is specified in the filter

        //if (filter.Id > 0)
        //    query = query.Where(t =>
        //        t.Name >= filter.NameFrom && t.Name <= filter.NameTo);
        if (filter.Id > 0)
            query = query.Where(t =>
                t.Id == filter.Id);

        if (filter.StatusTypeArray.Count() > 0)
            query = query.Where(t =>
                filter.StatusTypeArray.Contains(t.Status_Id));
        if (AppType.Count() > 0)
            query = query.Where(t =>
                 AppType.Contains(t.AppId));
        if (bankAccountArr.Count() > 0)
            query = query.Where(t =>
                bankAccountArr.Contains(t.BankAccount));
        if (filter.TransactionTypeArray.Count() > 0)
            query = query.Where(t =>
                filter.TransactionTypeArray.Contains(t.TransactionType_Id));
        if (filter.CurrencyTypeArray.Count() > 0)
            query = query.Where(t =>
                filter.CurrencyTypeArray.Contains(t.Currency));
        if (filter.Amount_From > 0)
            query = query.Where(t =>
                t.Amount >= filter.Amount_From);
        if (filter.Amount_To > 0 && filter.Amount_To >= filter.Amount_From)
            query = query.Where(t =>
                t.Amount >= filter.Amount_To);
        if (filter.CreationDate_From != null)
            query = query.Where(t =>
                t.CreationDate >= filter.CreationDate_From);
        if (filter.CreationDate_To != null)
            query = query.Where(t =>
                t.CreationDate <= filter.CreationDate_To);
        if (filter.AuditNumber != null && filter.AuditNumber != "")
            query = query.Where(t =>
                t.AuditNumber.Contains(filter.AuditNumber));
        if (filter.BankAccount != null && filter.BankAccount != "")
            query = query.Where(t =>
                t.BankAccount.Contains(filter.BankAccount));
        if (filter.BillingNumber != null && filter.BillingNumber != "")
            query = query.Where(t =>
                t.BillingNumber.Contains(filter.BillingNumber));
        if (filter.ServiceCode != null && filter.ServiceCode != "")
            query = query.Where(t =>
                t.ServiceCode.Contains(filter.ServiceCode));
        if (filter.TransactionNumber >= -1)
            query = query.Where(t =>
                t.TransactionNumber.ToString().Contains(filter.TransactionNumber.ToString()));
        if (filter.Client != null && filter.Client != "")
            query = query.Where(t =>
                t.Client.Contains(filter.Client));

        return query;
    }
```

4- Recuperación de Transactions

```
var query = GetQuery(pObject.Filter);
var listTrans = query.OrderByDescending(orderByFunc).Skip(pObject.Pagination.Index).Take(pObject.Pagination.Length).ToList();
```

5- Es posible haciendo un Select() en el punto 4 evitar traer Logs, Status y transactionType? para mejorar la consulta aun mas, algo así?

```
listTrans = query.OrderBy(orderByFunc).Skip(pObject.Pagination.Index).Take(pObject.Pagination.Length)
                    .Select(t => new Transaction()
                    {
                        Id = t.Id,
                        Amount = t.Amount,
                        AppId = t.AuditNumber
                    }).ToList();
```

Comment: veo que aplicas muuuuuchos mas filtros de los que mencionas, estas filtrando por fecha por montos, etc, no se a que te refieres con "utilizar un filtro para una consulta mucho mas personalizada" ? quiere decir que el take() funciona rapido cuando no defiens ningun filtro? esta claro que si filtras por muchos campos y estos no tienen indices en la tabla va a demorar

Comment: Por ejemplo en el pObject.Filter tengo 10 filtros para el where. Puedo utilizar los 10 como puedo utilizar 1.

Comment: Y si usas el take junto con los filtros?

Comment: 3 Preguntas: ¿Cuántos campos tiene esa tabla en tu base de datos?¿Cuántos índices tiene? ¿Cuánta CPU y RAM dispone tu servidor?

Comment: Fredyx te agregue a lo ultimo del post tu respuesta, indices casi nada o nada

Comment: pero el problema se presenta cuando aplicas uno o cuando aplicas varios ? esta claro, si aplicas varios filtros sobre campos no indexados vas a tener demora

Comment: El problema es cuando se aplican filtros actualmente, demora en exceso

Comment: recomendaria uses el Sql profiler para obtener la query SELECT que se esta ejecutando, la uses en el Management Studio y veas donde se genera la demora para asi determinar que indices debes crear en las tablas